# How can I replace Xubuntu with Lubuntu on a Windows XP laptop?

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu

I installed Xubuntu 11.10 on an old Windows XP in a separate partition. Later, I realized that I should have installed Lubuntu 11.10. Is there an easy way I can delete Xubuntu and replace it with a clean install of Lubuntu without deleting the partition? If not, what's the best way to delete Xubuntu and start over? By the way, this is my very first Linux install so I'm a definite newbie and would really like advice that does not involve using command lines. Thanks.

Comment: You know you could just install LXDE log out select it as your session log in, then remove XFCE and that's it.. no Command Line, no partitioning, no reinstalling,  no anything... and definitively not hard to do.

Answer (score 4):

Well I know you want advice that does not involve command lines but you only have to copy and paste one line into the terminal. (although you'll need a root terminal)

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T usually works)

type 
`sudo -i`

enter your password

copy and paste (paste in a terminal is CTRL+SHIFT+V) in:

`apt-get install lubuntu-desktop -y && apt-get remove xubuntu-desktop -y`

That's it

the "apt-get install" bit installs the ldxe desktop environment and all the programs that go with it, the "apt-get remove" bit removes all of xubuntu. You could also run `apt-get autoremove` to make sure everything has gone. Or you can just reinstall by downloading lubuntu and selecting remove xubuntu and install lubuntu instead during the install process.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Since I have Lubuntu installed on a USB flash drive can I boot from the USB drive and just click on the "Install Lubuntu" icon on the desktop? Would doing so give me the option to completely remove Xubuntu during the install process?

Comment: If you install, just install into the Xubuntu partition. That will remove xfce by over writing your data. If you want to keep your data, install lubuntu-desktop as suggested. You will have to remove more then xubuntu-desktop to remove all the xfce packages. See http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome

Comment: I second bodhi.zazen's comment. If you recently installed Xubuntu, I'm sure you don't have a ton of data. A clean install into the Xubuntu partition is absolutely the way to go. If you don't know how to do that, just ask and we'll give some pointers...

Comment: Oh... and welcome to Lubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to answer the first question but the second I can handle:

Best way to delete and start over is to format a usb key so it's FAT32 and then use a program like [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable disk.

Then all you need to do is set your bios so your computer boots from USB. You can do this at start-up by pressing one of the F keys (f2 or f4 or f8 something, I can't remember and it's different on each computer anyway - I just press them all and it usually works out ;-)) then you go into the page of the bios and change the order so USB is it's the first on the boot priority list.

Once you did this you need to save and exit it (be careful in the Bios too if you are not sure about anything I have said it is best to ask before fiddling about in there). Then reboot your computer and the lubuntu installer should prompt you for what to do next.

After that your computer will be all better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need a liveCD/liveusb Lubuntu. Insert it in your PC, boot in live mode. Open GParted and select your Xubuntu partition. Right-click and choose format/reformat to ext. Do not delete that partition. Just reformat it. Apply changes in GParted and close it. Click the Install Lubuntu icon. Install Lubuntu to the partition you just reformatted.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the software center or Synaptic to add the Lubuntu package, and boot into Lubuntu instead of Xubuntu on boot. Simple as that.

The answer from   Uri Herrera Jan 13 '12 at 22:51 is correct.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. Not only is this a VERY old post I commented on, but the answer was useful. I doubt the original poster even read it.Adding Lubuntu and logging in at boot in session manager screen is what I'd do, unless of course you have a low powered system without a lot of memory and/or small drive (almost impossible nowadays.) Then, you'd want to back up all your data and just install Lubuntu from USB stick and restore your data from the backup later.